# homestead.test took too long to respond

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have installed Laravel Homestead with Virtualbox and Vagrant and add a Laravel site. But I could not open the site.

Here's the Helpful Resources

**Git Bash**

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.4.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Running provisioner: file...
homestead: C:/Users/MyName/~/Homestead/aliases => /tmp/bash_aliases
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead:
homestead: ssh-rsa  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQCxiU+z6PvM4TqNL/a1nxxl
Tm6WXpF4FrDv32XkdfIyu3AtEAUeZ2w0vC9K+Hi0g7pnFYYasTkTQ
3HqLyFtBV/6lMIviH54berl some code missing by me for security 
dM+b6S+DaJ/GmcxS2SohYbrws2g8SbJqs5rYItZajhxy2ZegbKZ8FYLEla/w== aaaaaaa@gmail.com
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead: Ignoring feature: mariadb because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead: Ignoring feature: ohmyzsh because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
homestead: Ignoring feature: webdriver because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-18m1htu.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-1r070m2.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Certificate: homestead.test (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: homestead.test
homestead: Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
homestead: 1 added, 0 removed; done.
homestead: Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
homestead: done.
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Site: homestead.test (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: homestead.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-1fap55b.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Checking for old Schedule (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Certificate: mylaravelapp (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: mylaravelapp
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Site: mylaravelapp (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: mylaravelapp
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-1ydawr2.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Checking for old Schedule (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Clear Variables (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Restarting Cron (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Restarting Cron
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Restarting Nginx (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating MySQL Database: homestead (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: homestead
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Postgres Database: homestead (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: homestead
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating MySQL Database: mylaravelapp (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database: mylaravelapp
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Creating Postgres Database: mylaravelapp (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database: mylaravelapp
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Update Composer (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Update Composer
homestead: Updating to version 1.10.5 (stable channel).
homestead:
homestead: Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.10.1
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-bwenug.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Update motd (shell)...
homestead: Running: script: Update motd
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
homestead: Running: C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20200412-5936-klufsf.sh
```

**Host**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
   192.168.10.10  homestead.test
   192.168.10.10 mylaravelapp
```

**homestead.yaml**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code
    type: "nfs"
    mount_options: ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    - map: mylaravelapp
      to: /home/vagrant/code/mylaravelapp/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - mylaravelapp

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

**Ping**

```
C:\Users\MyName>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\MyName>ping 192.168.10.10

Pinging 192.168.10.10 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.10:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

**Browser Result**

```
This site can’t be reachedhomestead.test took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Note that: mylaravelapp exists in the 'code' Folder.

Is there any Solution/Suggestion?